# Tomcat fails to extract .war files

Tags: tomcat, war, alfresco

Our office has partnered with Alfresco and have been given enterprise licenses to install their software.  We are working off of RHEL6 application servers with tomcat6 installed via the command `yum install tomcat*` as well as the necessary java packages:

```
java-1.5.0-gcj.x86_64                      1.5.0.0-29.1.el6            @distro
java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64                  1:1.6.0.0-1.39.1.9.8.el6_1  @updates
java-1.6.0-sun.x86_64                      1:1.6.0.26-1jpp.1.el6       @supplementary
java-1.6.0-sun-devel.x86_64                1:1.6.0.26-1jpp.1.el6       @supplementary
java-1.6.0-sun-jdbc.x86_64                 1:1.6.0.26-1jpp.1.el6       @supplementary
java_cup.x86_64                            1:0.10k-5.el6               @distro
tomcat6-javadoc.noarch                     6.0.24-33.el6               @optional
tzdata-java.noarch                         2011g-1.el6                 @distro
apache-tomcat-apis.noarch                  0.1-1.el6                   @distro
tomcat6.noarch                             6.0.24-33.el6               @distro
tomcat6-admin-webapps.noarch               6.0.24-33.el6               @optional
tomcat6-docs-webapp.noarch                 6.0.24-33.el6               @optional
tomcat6-el-2.1-api.noarch                  6.0.24-33.el6               @distro
tomcat6-javadoc.noarch                     6.0.24-33.el6               @optional
tomcat6-jsp-2.1-api.noarch                 6.0.24-33.el6               @distro
tomcat6-lib.noarch                         6.0.24-33.el6               @distro
tomcat6-servlet-2.5-api.noarch             6.0.24-33.el6               @distro
tomcat6-webapps.noarch                     6.0.24-33.el6               @optional
tomcatjss.noarch                           2.1.0-1.el6                 @distro
```

After properly extracting the .war files into tomcat's webapps directory (as well as all other directories including shared, lib, etc...) and restarting tomcat via the command `service tomcat6 restart` it fails to extract the alfresco.war and share.war inside of the webapps directory.  I've seen articles discuss use of a startup.sh script that does not exist anywhere within my tomcat6 directory, and I assumed that restarting via the aforementioned command would be the equivalent.  Any possible ideas on how to get tomcat to extract on RHEL6 using the yum version of tomcat6?  By the way, as mentioned elsewhere on stackoverflow, I have also set the following variables in the /etc/profile file:

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/var/www/tomcat6
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.26.x86_64/
```

`$JAVA_HOME` contains the directories: bin, include, jre, and lib, assuming that is what I need to consider my JAVA_HOME.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Any chance you can post any relevant log line/error message?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use their Linux installer (*.bin) file?
It can be downloaded through the partner network site.

Make it/extract it to the place you want and then just use their settings.

If you take an earlier version of Alfresco e.g. 3.3.x then all the right tomcat runnable scripts will be in place

Comment: Unfortunately our security office is a little hesitant to use the pre-packaged bundle that includes software that is newer and unsupported by Redhat, when it is already in our yum repositories.  Would be ideal though I must admit.

Comment: don't use it though, just install it somewhere where you could take the config files from. I know that Alfresco has changed the way they ship Tomcat with the latest installations. In the earlier installations Tomcat was setup with the right startup/shutdown scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check your tomcat logs, especially for permissions related things. If you've copied the war files in by hand, these might be wrong, especially with a RHEL supplied service (RHEL tends to be pretty tight security wise, eg with SELinux)

You could also try grabbing a "hello world" type java app as a war, and see if that deploys properly. That way you can fix your deployment issues first, before you have to worry about if you've setup Alfresco correctly for it to start once deployed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, copying the file to the server was working bad

make sure you are copying the .war file correctly (by checksum)

or use a better tool to transfer your file.

[scp](https://www.garron.me/en/articles/scp.html) command is great for transferring file via ssh